# Rails 4 and gem (will_paginate) not deploying correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, will-paginate

I am working with Rails 4 and I am using this library for my pagination, but I have a problem when I deploy to production, I see this error:

> /home/deployer/apps/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in
>   require'/home/deployer/apps/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:inrequire':
>   No such file to load -- will_paginate/array (LoadError)

In development this library is working but in production I have this error, I was searching for this error on Google but I can't find a solution.

Do you have any idea what may be wrong? Let me know when you find out please.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, check that the `will_paginate` gem is enabled for production in your `Gemfile`. It may be under the `:development` group only.

Comment: Hi, in my Gemfile, it doesn't has group.